# Convert text string to date/time format in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I have a column with date/time info in following format stored as text:
`03.01.2011 09:55`.

How can I convert it to Date/Time format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A1 is the cell with the information in it then the following formula should work.

```
=DATE(MID(A1,7,4),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2))+RIGHT(A1,5)
```

This makes the assumption that `03.01.2011` is January 3rd. If it's March 1st, you need to swap the second and third terms in the `DATE` function.

Gansi's suggestion will not work for two reasons (one and a half, depending on your location regional settings).

1. Because changing a cell's format from text to a number does not automatically recalculate / alter the data in the cell - you'd need to re-enter the data (e.g. by pressing F2 and then enter)
2. (or 1 1/2)) In UK / US date formatting, Excel would not recognize the dots as delimiters in the date. This may not be true in other regions (possibly Germany?) where this usage is more common.

Comment: excellent, many thanks! it is exactly what i needed and could not figure it out myself. thanks again!